# Unable to get result in onActivityResult of Activity with a negative requestcode

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

I am trying to start another activity using `startActivityForResult` with a negative `requestCode` i.e.

```
startActivityForResult(intent,-1);
```

but as I finish my second activity I am not getting response in my first Activity. however positive request code is working fine and first activity is getting expected response.
I've seen documentation it doesn't say anything about signed request code.

Inside my second activity:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("resultObj",obj);
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: Why do you want to use negative request code?

Comment: did you read `Activity#startActivityForResult` documentation?

Comment: [`Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) --> [`Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int, Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)). That's where it explains negative request codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can change other request code. Example:

```
startActivityForResult(intent,999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like below and try:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("resultObj",obj);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(returnIntent,1);
getActivity().finish();
```

get this object in another class like below

```
ClassName model = (ClassName) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("resultObj");
```

And that class should implements Serializable

```
class ClassName implements Serializable {

}
```

Hope it will work..